# Why until loop does not execute at least once

Tags: bash, shell

I am just curious why this does not proceed at least once?!

```
until_loop=

    until [[ -z $until_loop ]]; do
       echo "Can't touch this!"
       until_loop="infinite_loop"
    done
```

But this yes

```
until_loop="proceed"

    until [[ -z $until_loop ]]; do
       echo "Stop me with ctrl-c!"
       until_loop="infinite_loop"
    done
```

Comment: See `help until` and `help test | grep -- -z`

Comment: You probably wanted to use `-n`, but used `-z`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `until` keyword is equivalent to `while !` (where `!` is a logical *NOT*). The exit status of the command

```
[[ -z $until_loop ]]
```

is checked **before** the body of the loop is run - it **doesn't** behave the same as a C-style

```
do { ... } while (...);
```

This means that if the condition is false to begin with, the loop will never run.

Comment: Great! I didn't see mention about this... and `-z` because I want to read until you let it empty.